# Hibernate 3 compatible with Java 1.6?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I'm trying to setup hibernate 3.2 in java 1.6 . Is it compatible with Java 1.6? because HSQLDB  2.2.6 requires java 1.6! Could anyone please help.

Comment: Yes, you can! There should be no problem with this. But why not use the latest stable hibernate version 3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate 3.2 should work in Java 6 (Java is always backward compatible at least one version).

Alternatively you can get the HSQLDB 2.2.6 jar compiled for Java 5.

It is available at http://hsqldb.org/support/

Also available on Maven. See here for the available jars which you can specify in your configuration:

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.2.6/

Please note you can use a hibernate dialect that is more compatible with 2.2.6. The dialect in Hibernate 3.2 is designed for HSQLDB 1.8.x. It works with 2.2.6, but for best results, you can use the legacy Hibernate 3.3 dialect that is supplied in the 2.2.6 distribution zip in the "integration" directory. You may need to modify this dialect a bit to work with Hibernate 3.2.